# Python Shell Script Running but Not running when calling it via crontab

Tags: python, linux, cron

Problem: I am trying to run a shell script which contains python script from Debian Linux env which is running properly but when I am calling it via crontab it is giving me an error below.

**error**

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/samsunguk/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/oauth2client/clientsecrets.py", line 121, in _loadfile
    with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './client_secrets.json'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/samsunguk/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 386, in LoadClientConfigFile
    client_type, client_info = clientsecrets.loadfile(client_config_file)
  File "/home/samsunguk/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/oauth2client/clientsecrets.py", line 165, in loadfile
    return _loadfile(filename)
  File "/home/samsunguk/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/oauth2client/clientsecrets.py", line 125, in _loadfile
    exc.strerror, exc.errno)
oauth2client.clientsecrets.InvalidClientSecretsError: ('Error opening file', './client_secrets.json', 'No such file or directory', 2)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/samsunguk/segmentTrendsandTraits/segmentTrend.py", line 193, in <module>
    extract_data(60, "csv_output_all_data_segments_BAAAM.csv", "output_data_segments_Last60days.csv", "output_data_segments_Last60days.xlsx")
  File "/home/samsunguk/segmentTrendsandTraits/segmentTrend.py", line 185, in extract_data
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
  File "/home/samsunguk/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 113, in _decorated
    self.GetFlow()
  File "/home/samsunguk/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 443, in GetFlow
    self.LoadClientConfig()
  File "/home/samsunguk/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 366, in LoadClientConfig
    self.LoadClientConfigFile()
  File "/home/samsunguk/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 388, in LoadClientConfigFile
    raise InvalidConfigError('Invalid client secrets file %s' % error)
pydrive.settings.InvalidConfigError: Invalid client secrets file ('Error opening file', './client_secrets.json', 'No such file or directory', 2)
```

My python script has google authorization credentials.

Can anyone help me why I am getting this error?

Comment: There's a big clue right in the error msg: "No such file or directory: './client_secrets.json'". So where is the file `clients_secrets.json` located?

Comment: @kaylum I know and as mentioned when running shell script itself it's not a concern but when calling it via crontab then it is giving an exception.

Comment: Yes, so where is the file located? Can't help you with correct suggestions if you don't provide the required info to us. Also, show your crontab entry.

Comment: @kaylum "21 4 * * 5 segmentTrendsandTraits/job.sh > segmentTrendsandTraits/output.log" this is the crontab entry and the file client_screts.json is in the same directory where the shell script and python script s

Comment: Please add that info into the question and not in the comments. `cron` runs the script from your home directory. So `.` in this case is your home directory and thus it won't find that `json` file. One solution to try is to change crontab to: `cd segmentTrendsandTraits; ./job.sh`

Comment: @kaylum Thanks for the suggestion it's working.